# Are comments on answers to my question supposed to show up in my recent activity

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Are comments on answers to my question supposed to show up in my recent activity? If not why not, I would like to know any activity on a question that I posted.

Request: Be notified of all activity on any question that I post including comments to answers posted to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I was going back and forth with comments on a particular answer to get clarification and didn't realize later on that someone had posted a comment that was directed to me. This happened to me on 4 different questions that I asked, and then the other person that was commenting doesn't come back either.

So as TheTXI pointed out "Comments on an answer posted by someone else will NOT show up."

I would like to be notified of any comments to a question/answer if I posted a comment to that question/answer even if I do not own the question or answer. I would also want to be notified of any comments to any answer of a question that I asked.

Maybe make that an option just like when you check the box next to Notify { email address } daily of new answers. You could flag your the question/answer that you comment on so that you are notified when someone else comments or edits the question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comments on your question will show up.

Answers on your question will show up.

Comments on an answer you post will show up.

Comments on an answer posted by someone else will NOT show up.

To answer the feature request, it would be nice to have as long as it mentioned that it was in response to a particular answer, that way I don't have to sit there and be confused momentarily thinking that the commenter is talking specifically to me.

Comment: @TheTXI : So if I did this then you would be notified because I used "@TheTXI" ?

Comment: @TheTXI : Don't you want to read any activity on a question that you asked?

Comment: Using the "@" symbol does not work the same as in Twitter. Here it is just to reduce confusion. There is no actual mechanism behind it to notify me of any replies. I will see your comment since you commented on my answer, but if you had posted that comment on your own answer I would not get notified. There have been suggestions in the past to implement the twitter-style reply notification, but nothing has come about it.

Comment: And I am not saying that I don't want to read the activity. of course I want to read the activity, I just don't want my recent activity notification to get me confused when I see the preview and I think that someone is responding to one of my answers or my question when they may be responding to something else I happen to be associated with (such as being the OP of a question)

Comment: @TheTXI: I was suggesting by using "@" that this would be a way to notify users, I know that there is no actual mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see this too - it's very annoying trying to find when I have further questioned an answer and have to recheck all q's manually to find updates.

Answer (score 0):

> Be notified of all activity on any question that I post including comments to answers posted to my question.

I don't think we'll be doing this -- it seems excessive, as a lot of the comments may not be directed at you, but the answerers themselves.

But we do have @user style comment notifications now:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

Comment: Crazy idea: why not notify for all *undirected* comments. That way question owners can get notified of comments on the answer itself, but not side conversations. Of course, this would require expanding the @user convention to apply to the owner of the post too.